# can't execute the blender python through subprocess

Tags: python

My blender is at the path of `'/home/abc/Destkop/blender/blender-2.78'`. When command line is at the path `'/home/abc/Destkop/blender/blender-2.78'`, executing `'./blender -b /home/abc/Destkop/blender/car.model'` through command line is working.

I am trying to execute blender in python through subprocess, but the code doesn't work with an error `"/usr/bin/python: can't open file ./blender -b /home/abc/Destkop/blender/car.model"`, but the path is all right

here is my code

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

if __name__="__main__":
    os.chdir("/home/abc/Destkop/blender/blender-2.78")
    subprocess.Popen([sys.executable],"./blender -b /home/abc/Destkop/blender/car.model ")
```

Answer (score 2):

First I expect you should use [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) rather than `popen`, which is a lower level call that offers more options that you aren't using.

I would suggest using a full path rather than the `./` prefix to a command.

The main source of your error is your arguments list, the first parameter to `run()` or `popen()` is called `args` and is the arguments used to run the external application. In your case you are passing the path to the current executable, which would be the python interpreter you are running the script in. The next argument is a single string, which python appears to be interpreting as a file path to a script to run.

The `arg` parameter should be a list of strings that you would use in a terminal, the first string is the executable and each following string would be each option passed to the executable.

By defining the list on multiple lines for clarity -

```
myargs = [
    "/home/abc/Destkop/blender/blender-2.78/blender",
    "-b",
    "/home/abc/Destkop/blender/car.model"
    ]
subprocess.run(myargs)
```

The full path can be made more flexible by using [bpy.app.binary_path](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.html#bpy.app.binary_path).

You also have a trailing space after the filename which would get interpreted as part of the filename.

Comment: thanks, sambler. subprocess is based on python3.5, while my system is based on python3.4 while many packages are based on python3.4

Comment: `run()` was added in 3.5, `call()` was used before that. Whether you use `popen()` or `call()` with 3.4, 3.5 or 2.7, the same applies to the args list that you pass to each method.

Comment: The main issue is, the `subprocess` calls by default do *not* pass the args through a shell (unless you specify `shell = True`). Therefore you cannot pass a shell command line, you must pass the individual word strings that the called program would access through the `argv` vector.

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the path to Blender, use [bpy.app.binary_path](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.html#bpy.app.binary_path). This is guaranteed to be correct, also on different platforms. I've updated the answer with this, as depending on the current working directory is rather fragile.

Comment: @dr.Sybren It would be if they were using blender. I'm sure this script is being run like a shell script to initially start blender.

Comment: @sambler oh man, you're right, I didn't even consider that. In that case would the question even belong here? Or is it a generic "how to start a subprocess" question about Python?